# Do the partial derivatives of this piecewise constant function exist? If yes, how can I compute them?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given this piecewise constant function

$$ f(x,a,b,c,d,e) =
\begin{cases}
a, & x \lt d; \\
c, & d \le x \lt e; \\
b, & e \le x. \\
\end{cases}
$$

do the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}f$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial b}f$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial c}f$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial d}f$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial e}f$ exist?

I would guess

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial a}f =
\begin{cases}
1, & x \lt d; \\
0, & d \le x. \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial c}f =
\begin{cases}
0, & x \lt d; \\
1, & d \le x \lt e; \\
0, & e \le x. \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b}f =
\begin{cases}
0, & x \lt e; \\
1, & e \le x. \\
\end{cases}
$$

but I have no idea on how to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial d}f$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial e}f$.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reasons you guessed the other derivatives:
$\partial_d f(x,a,b,c,\bar d, e) = 0$ unless $x = \bar d$ and $a\ne b$ or $a\ne c$ and $\bar d = e = x$ and analogously
$\partial_e f(x,a,b,c,d,\bar e) = 0$ unless $x=\bar e$ and $b\ne c$ or $a\ne c$ and $\bar e = d = x$
The undefined region for each derivative each is where $f$ has a jump discontinuity because of $a\ne b$ (or $a\ne c$ and $d=e$ so the middle case drops out)

Also note that all your partial derivatives are undefined at the jump points (so you must exchange all $\le$-signs by $<$-signs to be completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are $a,b,c,d,e$ all constants? If so only the weak derivative with respect to $x$ exists, and $\partial_xf=(c-a)\delta_d+(b-c)\delta_e$ ($\delta_x$ is the dirac delta function)

Comment: I say this because you said the function is peice wise constant, but it isn't if $a,b,...$ are not constant

Comment: $f$ is a function of the variable $x$ and the five parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$; when I fix the values of the five parameters I get a piecewise constant function.

Comment: In which case (taking $f$ piecewise constant) you cannot calculate the other partial derivatives, as this changed the nature of the function